# nest-vault package in kubernetes cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, nestjs, vault

I have an idea to paste dynamic database credentials in my nestJS application. For credentials storage i using Vault. Separately i installed vault client in nodejs container. This command

```
vault write auth/approle/login role_id=$ROLE_ID secret_id=$SECRET_ID
```

work's fine

```
Key                     Value
---                     -----
token                   s.FPuXg2It7Q6YeYW9QzWlQvnz
...
```

after this, i configured  nestVault module

```
ConfigModule.forRoot(),
NestVaultModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
    return {
      https: true,
      baseUrl: configService.get('VAULT_ADDR'),
      rootPath: 'secrets',
      timeout: 1000,
      proxy: false,
      cacert: '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt',
    };
  },
}),
```

for simple test i setup controller with code

```
return this.vault.healthCheck();
```

output

```
{"initialized":true,"sealed":false,"standby":false,"performance_standby":false,"replication_performance_mode":"disabled","replication_dr_mode":"disabled","server_time_utc":1649599674,"version":"1.9.2","cluster_name":"vault-cluster-3cc285da","cluster_id":"195b89dc-76bb-8b5d-3e22-ccd462812a86"}
```

but when i trying to login with code

```
const role_id = this.configService.get('ROLE_ID');
const secret_id = this.configService.get('SECRET_ID');
console.log(role_id, secret_id);
const token = await this.vault.loginWithAppRole({
  role_id: role_id,
  secret_id: secret_id,
}).client_token;
```

i getting error from nest js:

```
/backend/node_modules/hashi-vault-js/Vault.js:1590
      throw parseAxiosError(err);
            ^
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at Vault.loginWithAppRole (/backend/node_modules/hashi-vault-js/Vault.js:1590:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

and 502 from web server.
what could be wrong?

the same with

```
const ret = await this.vault.loginWithK8s(
  'internal-app',
  'token..',
);
console.log(ret);
```